# Python (pyautogui / selenium) salvar texto selecionado

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

Boa tarde!

Estou com uma duvida aqui e gostaria muito de uma ajuda:

Estou fazendo alguns testes aqui em python, automatizando o login ao instagram, acessando a pagina de seguidores e selecionando os nomes (da mesma forma que eu faria manualmente, mas utilizando dragTo do pyautogui) e apos isso aperto Control + C para copiar o campo selecionado. 
até esse ponto, esta tudo funcionando super bem, minha duvida é:

como pegar o texto que eu dei control + C a armazenar em uma variável? é possível?
se não, existe alguma forma alternativa de fazer isso?

segue a função que eu fiz até aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitas formas de se obter o conteúdo copiado em Python, sendo uma delas o pacote `pyperclip`. Esse pacote possui duas funções muito interessantes que são o `copy()` para copiar um texto e o `paste()` para colar.

Utilize a função `paste` para obter o conteúdo copiado e coloque o retorno em uma variável, dessa forma:

```
import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Jean, ajudou bastante!